# PHP Sign In - mysql_fetch_array returns NULL

Tags: php, mysql, account

I am attempting to get a simple account sign-in setup and functioning; However, when running my 'signIn' function I seem to keep hitting 'Unsuccessful login'.

I used the var_dump function trying to locate the problem, and saw that `var_dump($row['username']); die;` was returning NULL. I feel that the problem might be originating from my `mysql_query` or `mysql_fetch_array`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
    $host = 'localhost';
    $database = 'database_name';
    $username = 'username';
    $password = 'password';

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die('Connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    echo 'Connected successfully. ';

    mysql_select_db($database) or die('Unable to select database. ');

    $signIn = $_POST['signIn'];

    function signIn() {
        // Start session
        session_start();

        // Variables
        $ID = $_POST['username'];
        $Password = $_POST['password'];

        if (!empty($ID)) {
            $query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `signin` WHERE username = "$ID" AND password = "$Password"');
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);

            // Troubleshooting
            var_dump($row['username']); die;

            if (!empty($row['username']) AND !empty($row['password'])) {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $row['password'];

                echo "Successful login. ";
            } else {
                echo "Unsuccessful login. ";
            }
        }
    }

    if(isset($signIn)) {
        signIn();
    }
?>
```

Below is a screenshot of the current database table structure.

[image: Database screenshot]

Comment: Since you seem to be learning about PHP and databases, I suggest you learn something else than the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated a long time and have been removed in PHP 7. Although many (outdated) tutorials still exist, it's better to use a newer API like `MySQLi` or `PDO`. Also some warning about *SQL injection*, to which your script is vulnerable.

Comment: Whichever API you use. They all have functions for getting the actual error information that explains why you couldn't get a result from the query. That will probably tell you that you got a syntax error, because you used double quotes instead of single quotes around `"$ID"` and `"$Password" `.

Comment: @GolezTrol - not quite. It'll be because the query in `mysql_query` is using single quotes, so PHP treats it as a literal and doesn't interpolate the values for `$ID` and `$Password`.

Comment: Thank you @GolezTrol and @andrewsi! I appreciate the information. Removing the single quotes in the query did the trick.

Comment: @andrewsi Good point. That will be an even bigger issue. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is variable interpolation:

```
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `signin` WHERE username = "$ID" AND password = "$Password"');
```

single quotes will not expand $ID and $Password to their values in the query, you need to use double quotes:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `signin` WHERE username = '$ID' AND password = '$Password'");
```